# How to implement another var parameter name for the route

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

and when I try to use a parameter like

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public JsonResult ShowProductsPerPage(string pageNumber)
{ ...
```

It is not working

but when I use

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public JsonResult ShowProductsPerPage(string id)
{ ...
```

It is working fine.

Here JS

```
    var currentUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
    var url = currentUrl + "/Products/ShowProductsPerPage/" + pageNumber;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.pageNumber);
        }
    });
```

I use in JavaScript the variable `pageNumber` so I'd like to keep the same name for the 
code behind methods.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Just change {id} in the route to {pageNumber}.

Comment: Show us how you post data to controller

Comment: @Dennisch But what about other methods when I use `id`? They will not work.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't have two routes with exactly the same parameters, only with different names. You could add the pageNumber in the querystring, and add it as an optional parameter to the route.

Comment: @Dennisch Yeah I know about it. I'd like to change the primary parameter it is impossible that it will be like `id` always...

Comment: @karaxuna Done. Pls take a look at.

Comment: Ah, you did not mention that. I'd say its best to just keep the id and add the pageNumber as a parameter in the querystring, then you can just add it to the methods nwhere you want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

- The first is (as the comments have said), to change `{id}` to `{pageNumber}` in your existing route.
- The second is to create a new route, which differs in some way and takes a `{pageNumber}`.  Put this route before your existing one:

.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageNumber",
    url: "Products/ShowProductsPerPage/{pageNumber}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "ShowProductsPerPage" }
 );
```

- The third way is to explicitly pass `pageNumber` as a parameter: `/Products/ShowProductsPerPage?pageNumber=5`

Comment: Thanks! I just checked #2 and that is what I need.

Comment: They'd all work, and the best one depends on the situation.  I'm glad you found one that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just change {id} in the route to {pageNumber} (and also the corresponding urlparameter). There are no rules on what names parameters should have, id is just a regularily used one.

Answer (score 0):

Change your call to :

```
var url = currentUrl + "/Products/ShowProductsPerPage?pageNumber=" + pageNumber;
```